# Custom validation message not showing up using validation @Html.validationmessagefor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have developed custom validation attribute which verifies if the mobile number and email address entered by the user already exists in the database, if it doesn't exists it will create a new user else it will show an error message which says Mobile number or Email already exists.

The below is custom validation attribute which works as expected(I tested it in debug mode).

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace RBSSTATE.Models
{
    public class VerifyUserExistance:ValidationAttribute
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext _context;
        public VerifyUserExistance()
        {
            _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var user =(RegisterViewModel) validationContext.ObjectInstance;
            var foundEmail= _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email.Equals(user.Email));
            var foundPhoneNumber = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PhoneNumber == user.PhoneNumber);
            if (foundEmail != null || foundPhoneNumber != null)
                return new ValidationResult("Email or Phone Number already exists");
            return ValidationResult.Success;
       }
    }
}
```

This is my model

```
  [Required]
  [VerifyUserExistance]
  [RegularExpression(@"^04([0-9]){8}$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Mobile Number")]
  public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
  [Required]
  [VerifyUserExistance]
  [EmailAddress]
  [Display(Name = "Email")]
  public string Email { get; set; }
```

This is .CSHtml code where validation message should be displayed(It display other validation messages except validation message for attribute [VerifyUserExistance])

```
 <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.PhoneNumber)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PhoneNumber, new { @class = "form-control form-control-lg", placeholder = "Phone Number" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.PhoneNumber, "", new { @style = "color:red" })
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Email)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email, new { @class = "form-control form-control-lg", placeholder = "Email" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Email, "", new { @style = "color:red" })
 </div>
```

Please help. I tried different things but didn't work.

Comment: You have checked modelstate is valid in code behind?

Comment: Yes but the code execution will not get to register method  until the code doesn't have any validation errors